# Nested GroupBy in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, group-by

Having an object with this structure:

```
public class GroupedObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

---

Here it is grouped by one of its attributes, `id`.

```
var myObj = someResponse
    .Select(d => new GroupedObject
    {
        id = d.id,
        name = d.name,
        value = d.value,
        color = d.color
    })
    .GroupBy(o => o.id)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Select(o => o).ToList());
```

The structure is:

```
id - id, name, value, color
id - id, name, value, color
id - id, name, value, color
```

What I want to do is to group it again by `name`, to have a nested structure like this:

```
id - name - id, name, value, color
   - name - id, name, value, color
id - name - id, name, value, color
   - name - id, name, value, color 
   - name - id, name, value, color 
   - name - id, name, value, color 
id - name - id, name, value, color
   - name - id, name, value, color 
   - name - id, name, value, color
```

Trying to use `GroupBy` twice didn't work. Neither by transforming it with `ToList` and grouping after that.

```
 var myObj = someResponse
        .Select(d => new GroupedObject
        {
            id = d.id,
            name = d.name,
            value = d.value,
            color = d.color
        })
        .GroupBy(o => o.id).GroupBy(o => o.name)
        .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Select(o => o).ToList());
```

Comment: Surely you have to ToDictionary the first GroupBy and then instead of doing a.Select... in the ToDictionary, you'd have a.GroupBy and chain an entire ToDictionary to that with another .Select.

Comment: Your desired end result should look like this? `Dictionary<int, Dictionay<string, List<GroupedObject>>` - where the `int` key of the outer `Dictionary` is the `id` and the `string` key of the inner `Dictionary` is the `name` ?

Comment: @RandRandom Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, however here is the LINQ to achieve two nested levels of grouping:

```
someResponse
    .Select(d => new GroupedObject
    { 
        id = d.id,
        name = d.name,
        value = d.value,
        color = d.color
    })
    .GroupBy(o => o.id)
    .ToDictionary(
        a => a.Key,
        a => a.GroupBy(o => o.name).ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o));
```

This will result in object of type: `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, IGrouping<string, GroupedObject>>>`

Taken that into account, last `IGrouping<string, GroupedObject>` type can be changed/projected into different type specifying suitable lamda inside nested `ToDictionary` call:

e.g. Changing call into `ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.ToList())` results with `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<GroupedObject>>>`

Comment: Propably want to change `o => o` to `o => o.ToList()` to "resolve" the group and get the following type: `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<GroupedObject>>` .. to late

Comment: @RandRandom I agree, that's why I've edited question with that example, I just wanted to show OP possibilities since I'm not sure what type he actually wants to have

Answer (score 0):

Using comprehension syntax might be easier:

```
var myObj = from sr in someResponse
    .Select(d => new GroupedObject
    {
        id = d.id,
        name = d.name,
        value = d.value,
        color = d.color
    })
    group sr by sr.id into g1
    select new {
       ID = g1.Key,
       NamesGroup = from n in g1
                    group n by n.name into g2
                    select new {
                      Name = g2.Key,
                      ...
                    }
    };
```

Note: If you download then wonderful LINQPad from LINQPad.net, in Samples you would find a very nice nested grouping sample using Northwind sample database.